# Using Pyinstaller to convert to exe.FileNotFoundError: 'C:\\Users\\{ [8240] Username}\\\_MEI98802\\astor\\VERSION'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pyinstaller

Problem occuring in this line :

`from keras import backend as K`

I am converting a python source code which uses tensorflow and keras API for testing data.
Using pyinstaller to convert it into exe in Windows OS. I am getting below error related to astor file version. I don't know why i am getting this error after executing the exe file. I am getting no error while running the source code as python filename.py
Using
        Python 3.7 
        tensorflow==1.15
        keras==2.0.3

`from keras import backend as K` is written in exterior file which is imported to main file.

```
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\keras\activations.py", line 3, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 28, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\standard_ops.py", line 25, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\__init__.py", line 37, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\core\converter.py", line 71, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\cfg.py", line 41, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\pyct\compiler.py", line 32, in <module>
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 489, in exec_module
  exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
File "site-packages\astor\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\{Username}\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI98802\\astor\\VERSION'
[8240] Failed to execute script test_exec
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to downgrade `astor` to 0.7.1 and `pyinstaller` to 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. My astor package version was 0.8.1. I changed astor version to 0.7.1. It worked for me. pyinstaller version 3.6